# Making a list sortable in ASP.NET MVC using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to figure out how to implement jquery sortable..

I have a page with a bunch of attributes grouped by category, like this:

- CategoryA

  - Attribute1
  - Attribute2
  - Attribute3
  - Attribute4
- CategoryB

  - Attribute5
  - Attribute6
  - Attribute7
  - Attribute8
- CategoryC

  - Attribute9
  - Attribute10
  - Attribute11
  - Attribute12

The ultimate solution would be to be able to sort everything; sort parents (categories), sort attributes (children) and move attributes between categories with Drag-And-Drop!....
But I'm guessing that is stretching it right now..

So, just being able to sort the attributes under each category with Drag-And-Drop would be a nice start..
I've been looking at jquery sortable which seems to do this, but how do I implement it?
I'm guessing I need one script for each category...

Something like this: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquerydragdrop/

ASP.NET 4, EF 4, ASP.NET MVC 3, Razor views...

This is what I've got to work with:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ArrangeAttributesViewModel</legend>
        @foreach (var _category in Model.AllAttributesForCheckBoxList.AttributeList)
        {
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <div id="@_category.CategoryName">
                @_category.CategoryName
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in _category.AttributesList)
                    {
                        <li id="@item.Priority.ToString()">
                            @Html.CheckBox(item.AttributeID.ToString(), item.Chosen)
                            @(" " + item.AttributeTitle)
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Any ideas?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unless priority is alphanumeric and starts with a letter, you're going to have invalid ids for your attribute `li` elements.

Comment: OK, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over them, but using a class for the `ul` elements would help to distinguish them. Using `containment` parent to constrain their movement to the parent element might make the intent clearer, but unless you specify the `connectWith` option they should stay within their respective lists.  See a simple example at http://jsfiddle.net/R4afy/

```
    <div id="@_category.CategoryName">
        @_category.CategoryName
        <ul class="sortable-container">
            @foreach (var item in _category.AttributesList)
            {
                <li id="@("P" + item.Priority.ToString())">
                    @Html.CheckBox(item.AttributeID.ToString(), item.Chosen)
                    @(" " + item.AttributeTitle)
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
          $('.sortable-container').sortable({
              containment: 'parent'
          });
     });
</script>
```

Note: This doesn't address persisting the sort order chosen.  To do that you'd need additional code outside the scope of your stated problem.  Unless the ability to sort is simply to help the user identify elements on this page, I think you'll find recording the order is pretty important.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work, which jquery files do I need to add? Now I have: 
jquery-ui-1.8.11.js and jquery-1.5.1.js

Comment: @bek for the example I used jQuery 1.6 and jQuery UI 1.8.13.

Comment: Apparently the order of which the two script references are written matters, ui should be below the other... Now it's sortable, just trying to figure out how to save the new order..

Comment: @bek - yes, jQuery UI is dependent on jQuery itself.

Comment: Did I say I was a beginner ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not to toot my own horn, but I think a plugin I wrote is just right for what you're trying to do. It lets you sort lists depending on HTML data attributes, so you might have to tweak your markup a bit, but in general I think it's what you're looking for.

https://github.com/jszpila/jquery.listSorter

Comment: unfortunately your web link isnt working.. is there a demo on there?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was kind of vague.. I would like to have some kind of drag-and-drop sorting, cause there's no property to sort by..